# React Native Typescript styled components error

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components

I keep getting the following error when trying to use styled components in react native and typescript:

```
WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
Error: Directory for 'file:///Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/12EBA58B-1919-42F7-A255-0AB501875563/data/Containers/Data/Application/8BD96CA0-A291-4840-A694-EB6F0D92867F/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FDrinklink-c6446bc2-812f-446d-b2ff-ff09cb07de2a/ExponentAsset-b62641afc9ab487008e996a5c5865e56.ttf' doesn't exist.
```

Installed with:
yarn add @types/styled-components-react-native
So I have version 5.1.3

Imported by:
import styled from "styled-components/native";

Styled component code:

```
const Title = styled.Text`
  padding: 16px;
`;
export type Props = {
  vendor: any;
};

const VendorInfo: React.FC<Props> = ({ vendor }) => {
  const { title, image } = vendor;
  return (
    <Card elevation={5} style={styles.card}>
      <Card.Cover style={styles.cover} source={{ uri: image }} />
      <Title>{title}</Title>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

Ive tried various things to get styled components react native to work and so far have had no luck.  Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a resolutions section in package.json?

```
{
  "resolutions": {
    "styled-components": "^5"
  }
}
```

And then run yarn install again

Comment: I did not - but my packages already installed at version 5."@types/styled-components-react-native": "^5.1.3", "styled-components": "^5.3.5"